# MakeRequest doesn't work

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I do request:

And I receive XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<search>
<location id="18171" client_id="511">
<site>3</site>
.....
```

After refresh browser I receive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    </search>
```

Only If i close and open browser I receive

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <search>
    <location id="18171" client_id="511">
    <site>3</site>
```

Why? I don't want to close and open browser everytime

Thank you

My code:

```
function makeRequestXML(url) {
    http_request = false;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
        http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (http_request.overrideMimeType) {
            http_request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
        }
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
        try {
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {}
        }
    }

    if (!http_request) {
        alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
        return false;
    }
    http_request.onreadystatechange = ContentsXML;
    http_request.open('GET', url, true);
    http_request.send(null);
}

function ContentsXML() {
    if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
        if (http_request.status == 200) {
            number_checkbox = 0;
            var xmldoc = http_request.responseXML;
```

Comment: Your code got cut off, can you add the rest of it?

Answer (score 0):

This a problem with your server you are connecting to.  I have no idea what it's doing, or what you expect it to be doing, but your JS is clearly hitting that server and returning data in all cases.  If you are getting back bad data, that is not the fault of your JS.

It seems like the server may be sending different data based on the browser session, and relaunching the browser may reset that session.

Comment: How can I reset that session? Maybe pop-up?

Comment: That's entirely dependent on how the server you are sending requests to works.  You may be able to delete a cookie or something, but its hard to advise here...

Comment: _That's entirely dependent on how the server you are sending requests to works._

Comment: I don't know it. I can only guess